# Is there an accepted test corpus for testing HTTP header parsing?

Tags: http, parsing, testing

I have some parser for HTTP request headers which claims to adhere to RFC 2616/723[0-1].  This parser is used to parse application-visible headers appearing in the HTTP request, such as `Accept`.

I'd like to test the quality of this parser by running it against a corpus of known-good and known-bad sample input.  It would be good if the corpus included edge-cases and any known attacks on parsers of those headers.

eg:

```
Accept: ,     text/html;q=0.5    // pass
Accept: "qdfa=;0.5               // fail
Accept: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  // attempted ReDoS on O(n^2) regex?
```

**Does a recognized test corpus exist for this purpose?**

Comment: My Google-fu has failed me thus far :-\